# AWS Athena Drop View named in Chinese

Tags: amazon-web-services, view, amazon-athena, naming

I'm new to Athena platform and I've checked if there's similar question to solve my problem.
I'm wondering if anyone knows how to delete a created view which is named in Chinese on Athena. It works when the view is named in English but not in Chinese. It seems only the first character can be recognized as attached screenshot. Much appreciation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dANTr.png)

Comment: did you try putting it in single and/or double quotes?

Comment: Just tried and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a programmatic way to drop a table you can try enclosing the name of the table with double quotes:

```
drop table "<name here>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage (and delete) Amazon Athena Views from the AWS Glue console.